# Error 121 Problem with NeoVim nvim and COC

Tags: neovim, coc.nvim

I'm trying for hours to fix this error message.
[Error message 121 I receive every time I load nvim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boyc1.png)
After a :CheckHealth command in nvim, it tells me that this has to do with COC, COC is impossible to initialize
[:CheckHealth in nvim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1eDK.png)

I am using Ubuntu on Windows 10 and nvim latest version.[enter image description here.

I don't find any solution on the internet.

I tried to modify my init.nvim.
To update all of my plugins in nvim.

Comment: Open an issue there? You may get better help.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in latest release, please upgrade your coc.nvim.